# Update view elements on page scroll event of view pager in android

Tags: android-viewpager, view

I just followed the below tutorial which is using simple layouts rather than fragments.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/viewpager-without-fragments/

I am able to achieve the UI. Now I want to update the left/right view elements based on the scroll position (left/right) of the center view in the view pager. Searched a lot. Not got a clear answer. Please help....